# how to create table with checkbox in every row and can select all i using datatables and bootstart

Tags: php, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
});
```

```html
select All
<input type="checkbox" name="all"> <br>
<table id="example1" class="display table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <th>Finger Id</th>
            <th>NIK</th>
            <th>Nama Staff</th>
            <th>Departement</th>
            <th>Jabatan</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What you have tried, show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I have done is named all your checkbox `name="selectThis"` and `selectAll(this)` in `<input type="checkbox" name="all" onClick="selectAll(this)"` in select all input

Then when select all checkbox is clicked `selectAll(this)` function is called and it loops all the other checkbox and checks it

```js
function selectAll(data) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('selectThis');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = data.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
select All
<input type="checkbox" name="all" onClick="selectAll(this)"> <br>
<table id="example1" class="display table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <th>Finger Id</th>
            <th>NIK</th>
            <th>Nama Staff</th>
            <th>Departement</th>
            <th>Jabatan</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5);">
            <td>Finger Id</td>
            <td>NIK</td>
            <td>Nama Staff</td>
            <td>Departement</td>
            <td>Jabatan</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectThis"></td>
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how if i use id, not name ,, because name i will using for insert